# How to configure Ubuntu to accept magick packets?

Tags: wakeup, wakeonlan

How to configure a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to accept magick packets?

I've already set at the setup the option to accept the boot from the network.

I tried to install ethtool too, but I could't go ahead. What's the next step?

`sudo ethtool wlan0` returns:

Settings for wlan0:

Link detected: yes

Could this hold with wireless connections? =/ Maybe not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this page : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan

Wireless connections typically don't work ; wired connections work over a wireless ethernet bridge in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ubuntu thing, and it cannot be as Ubuntu is not running when these packets are received. Check your bios, it's configured in there.

Comment: I'd checked the bios and is enabled. I've tried send a magick packet from Mac with `wakeonlan -i 255.255.255.0 c0:18:25:25:8b:8a`, because the ip is `192.168.10.123`, but didn't worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: The card needs to be put into a listening state for it to work. See the community wiki page for instructions.

Comment: mac and linux machine are on the same wired network? `c0:18:25:25:8b:8a` is the linux machine's mac (I'm guessing 'no' as it's not known at ieee)? You're using the built-in network card?